# Fast Algorithm for finding largest values in 2d array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

I have a 2D array (an image actually) that is size N x N.  I need to find the indices of the M largest values in the array  ( M << N x N) .  Linearized index or the 2D coords are both fine.  The array must remain intact (since it's an image).  I can make a copy for scratch, but sorting the array will bugger up the indices.

I'm fine with doing a full pass over the array (ie. O(N^2) is fine).  Anyone have a good algorithm for doing this as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Is there some pattern to the data or are we talking about purely random distribution? In that case N^2 is not that bad - it's basically linear to your data size.

Comment: If you are willing to do CPU-specific cache line optimizations, and you know the width of your data and the storage order of your data, you can pre-fetch the "next" cache line's worth of data at the head of your loop, so that it is in the CPU L1/L2 cache prior to usage for comparison.  This can speed up the algorithm by an order or two of magnitude.

Comment: At least you can slice the array and parallel the process, if it is supposed to run on multi-core cpu.

Comment: @Andy: An order *or two* of magnitude? I want to see some figures.

Comment: @TonyK: it is indeed the case. For instance with large (say 1000x1000) matrix multiplications stored in the same way, doing the naive 3-loops versus transposing one matrix and doing the loops in the right direction yields something between 5 and 10 times faster (depending on instruction set used), on run-of-the-mill Core2 duo desktop PCs (I did some benchmarks to convince my colleagues to use tuned BLAS implementations). Transposing the matrix becomes negligible since it is O(N^2) vs O(N^3) for the multiplication, and it showed us that cache locality **is** something to care about.

Comment: @Andy Good idea, but CPU-specific won't work here.

Comment: Is it by the way M pixels with largest values, or M largest values of the histogram?

Comment: @Alexandre: That is not "an order or two"; that is "up to an order". I was right to be skeptical.

Comment: @TonyK: if you measures orders in log base 2, this is rather three orders :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) is sorting's austere sister* (repeat this ten times in a row). Selection algorithms are less known than sort algorithms, but nonetheless useful.

You can't do better than O(N^2) (in N) here, since nothing indicates that you must not visit each element of the array.

A good approach is to keep a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) made of the M largest elements. This makes something O(N x N x log M).

You traverse the array, enqueuing pairs (elements, index) as you go. The queue keeps its elements sorted by first component.

Once the queue has M elements, instead of enqueuing you now:

1. Query the min element of the queue
2. If the current element of the array is greater, insert it into the queue and discard the min element of the queue
3. Else do nothing.

If M is bigger, sorting the array is preferable.

**NOTE:** @Andy Finkenstadt makes a good point (in the comments to your question) : you definitely should traverse your array in the "direction of data locality": make sure that you read memory contiguously.

Also, this is trivially parallelizable, the only non parallelizable part is when you merge the queues when joining the sub processes.

Comment: Ya a priority queue was the idea I was playing with.  I'm looking for a solution which efficiently minimizes the amount of sorting I have to do.  I suppose I can reduce the insert step by using a tree / heap instead of just a queue.

Comment: @wallacer: see the wikipedia article: priority queues have many different possible implementations. Make sure you take one which inserts, pops and peeks at the least value in the least amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the array into a single dimensioned array of tuples (value, original X, original Y ) and build a basic heap out of it in (O(n) time), provided you implement the heap as an array.

You could then retrieve the M largest tuples in O(M lg n) time and reference their original x and y from the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a copy of the input array in order to do a sort, that's way worse than just walking linearly through the whole thing to pick out numbers.

So the question is how big is your M? If it is small, you can store results (i.e. structs with 2D indexes and values) in a simple array or a vector.  That'll minimize heap operations but when you find a larger value than what's in your vector, you'll have to shift things around.

If you expect M to get really large, then you may need a better data structure like a binary tree (std::set) or use sorted std::deque.  std::set will reduce number of times elements must be shifted in memory, while if you use std::deque, it'll do some shifting, but it'll reduce number of times you have to go to the heap significantly, which may give you better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't use the 2 dimensions in any interesting way, it is easier to consiger the equivalent problem in a 2d array.

There are 2 main ways to solve this problem:

1. Mantain a set of M largest elements, and iterate through the array. (Using a heap allows you to do this efficiently).

   This is simple and is probably better in your case (M << N)
2. Use selection, (the following algorithm is an adaptation of quicksort):

   - Create an auxiliary array, containing the indexes [1..N].
   - Choose an arbritary index (and corresponding value), and partition the index array so that indexes corresponding to elements less go to the left, and bigger elements go to the right.
   - Repeat the process, binary search style until you narrow down the M largest elements.

   This is good for cases with large M. If you want to avoid worst case issues (the same quicksort has) then look at more advanced algorithms, (like median of medians selection)

Answer (score 0):

How many times do you search for the largest value from the array?
If you only search 1 time, then just scan through it keeping the M largest ones.

If you do it many times, just insert the values into a sorted list (probably best implemented as a balanced tree).